# Add a scrollbar to yfiles.canvas.Control

Tags: yfiles

I have a `yfiles.canvas.Control`, with some nodes inside. However, the number of nodes is getting bigger, and I need to add a scrollbar in order to vertically navigate through them, despite the reduced size in height.

How can I do this? I see that a [ScrollBar](http://docs.yworks.com/yfileshtml/html/T_eb95c13b-0404-1a88-1996-f370efa6b346.htm) class exists, but I don't know how to integrate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yFiles for HTML comes with scrollbars built in. You can [customize their visibility](http://docs.yworks.com/yfileshtmlv2/index.html#/api/yfiles.canvas.CanvasControl#CanvasControl-property-verticalScrollBarPolicy), but by default they will be shown as soon as the content rectangle is larger than the visible area. Maybe calling [updateContentRect](http://docs.yworks.com/yfileshtmlv2/index.html#/api/yfiles.canvas.CanvasControl#CanvasControl-method-updateContentRect) is all that is missing in your code?